# Switch integral and sum for Bessel function.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I haven't real knowledge in Bessel's function and I'd like to know how to switch integral and sum in these two equations. I've already tried a lot of ideas but nothing really works. The first one is :

$$
h(r, \theta, t) = \int_{\lambda = 0}^{+ \infty}\sum_{n \geq 1} e^{- \lambda^2 t/2} \lambda \sin\big(\frac{n \pi \theta}{\beta}\big) \sin\big(\frac{n \pi \theta_0}{\beta}\big) \mathbf{J}_{\frac{n\pi}{\beta}}(\lambda r_0) \mathbf{J}_{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}}(\lambda r) \text{ d}\lambda
$$
where $\mathbf{J}_{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}}$ is the Bessel's function of the first kind of order $\frac{n \pi}{\beta}$ and $\beta$, $\theta_0$ and $r_0$ are constants.

I've tried to apply the Fubini/Tonelli theorem's but I can't easily show up (and even know if it's true or not) that:
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} |\mathbf{J}_{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}} (\lambda r_0) \mathbf{J}_{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}} (\lambda r) | < \infty.
$$

The other equation is, I think, harder :

$$F(t)=
\int_{r=0}^{+\infty} \int_{\theta=0}^{\beta} \frac{2r}{\beta t} \sum_{n\geq 1} \sin\big( \frac{n \pi \theta_0}{\beta} \big) \sin\big(\frac{n \pi \theta}{\beta} \big) \exp\big( - \frac{r_0^2 + r^2}{2t} \big) \mathbf{I}_{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}} \big( \frac{r r_0}{t} \big) \text{ d}r \text{ d}\theta
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}}$ is the modified Bessel's function of the first kind.

I thank you in advance,

Hiz.

EDIT : Ok, I've found my answer. We've to use these two inegalities :
$$
\mathbf{J}_{\nu}(x)  \leq x^{\nu} \frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu + 1)} \\
\mathbf{I}_{\nu}(x)  \leq \frac{x^{\nu}}{2^{\nu} \Gamma(\nu +1)} e^x
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.With the Stirling formula and the Alembert rule we can conclude that the sums converge. To finish this proof,I just need to calculate explicitly these two sum :

$$
\sum_n \Big(\frac{\lambda r}{2}\Big)^{\frac{n\pi}{\beta}}\frac{1}{\Gamma\big(\frac{n \pi}{\beta} + 1\big)} \\
\sum_n \Big(\frac{rr_0}{2t}\Big)^{\frac{n \pi}{\beta}}\frac{1}{\Gamma\big( \frac{n \pi}{\beta} + 1\big)}.
$$